# get vector between 2 rectangles

Tags: c#, math

suppose I have 2 rectangles as follows:

1. one encloses the other
2. they share at least 2 sides (3 or all 4 also possible)

how do I get the vector that describes the displacement required for the inner rectangle to move upto the non-shared side(s)?

Comment: yes, but the function in which I calculate this does not have access to the Canvas, I really need just the offset / vector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understood you correctly, then you you should follow those steps:

1. Find corner that both sides are shared.
2. Get oposit corner from inner and outer rectangles.
3. `vector = outerRecCorner - innerRecCorner`

Comment: that sounds like what I need but it does not take into account displacement limited to the horizontal or vertical plane (3 shared sides) nor non-displacement (4 shared sides)

Comment: with 3 shared sides it will give you vector orthogonal to one of the sides. With 4 sides result will be [0,0] so it will be correct answer.

Comment: Yes it does: in step 1, just find _any_ corner shared by both rectangles. The remaining steps will then work.

Comment: I may have commented too quick there, this will indeed work, thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

It's more like a math than programming question :)

Lets assume you have two rectangles: A (inside) and B (outside). They have 4 corners:

```
Point [] GetCorners (Rectangle rect)
{
   Point [] corners = new Point[4];

   Point corners[0] = new Point(rect.X, rect.Y);
   Point corners[1] = new Point(rect.X + rect.Width, rect.Y);
   Point corners[2] = new Point(rect.X, rect.Y + rect.Height);
   Point corners[3] = new Point(rect.X + rect.Width + rect.Width, rect.Y);

   return corners;
}
```

First find the first shared corner:

```
Point [] cornersListA = GetCorners(A);
Point [] cornersListB = GetCorners(B);

int sharedCornerIndex = 0;
for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
  if(cornersListA[i].X==cornersListB[i].X && cornersListA[i].Y==cornersListB[i].Y)
  {
     sharedCornerIndex = i;
     break;
  }
}
```

Then find the corner oposite of it:

```
int oppositeCornerIndex = 0;
if(sharedCornerIndex ==0) oppositeCornerIndex = 3;
if(sharedCornerIndex ==3) oppositeCornerIndex = 0;
if(sharedCornerIndex ==1) oppositeCornerIndex = 2;
if(sharedCornerIndex ==2) oppositeCornerIndex = 1;
```

Finally, get vector (I didn't check this part of the code, but it should work):

```
Vector v = new Vector();
v.X = cornersListB[oppositeCornerIndex].X - cornersListA[oppositeCornerIndex].X;
v.Y = cornersListB[oppositeCornerIndex].Y - cornersListA[oppositeCornerIndex].Y;
```

Comment: +1 thanks for such a detailed answer! I have retagged the question to include 'math' and I will definitely use this (but refactor it a bit using linq), thanks again!